# python import nltk failed

Tags: python, import, module, nltk

I want to use nltk module; however, when I try to import this module, I got the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 441, in <module>
import threading
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 7, in <module>
from traceback import format_exc as _format_exc
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/traceback.py", line 5, in <module>
import linecache
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/linecache.py", line 11, in <module>
import tokenize
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/tokenize.py", line 34, in <module>
from token import *
File "/Users/1/Desktop/classes/SI650/token.py", line 3, in <module>
from nltk import pos_tag
ImportError: cannot import name 'pos_tag'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "token.py", line 3, in <module>
from nltk import pos_tag
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/nltk/__init__.py", line 89, in <module>
from nltk.internals import config_java
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/nltk/internals.py", line 11, in <module>
import subprocess
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 443, in <module>
import dummy_threading as threading
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/dummy_threading.py", line 45, in <module>
import threading
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 7, in <module>
from traceback import format_exc as _format_exc
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/traceback.py", line 5, in <module>
import linecache
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/linecache.py", line 11, in <module>
import tokenize
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/tokenize.py", line 34, in <module>
from token import *
File "/Users/1/Desktop/classes/SI650/token.py", line 3, in <module>
from nltk import pos_tag
ImportError: cannot import name 'pos_tag'
```

But when i use terminal to change my directory to the desktop, everything is fine.

```
$ cd Desktop
1tekiMacBook-Air:Desktop 1$ python3
Python 3.5.2 (v3.5.2:4def2a2901a5, Jun 26 2016, 10:47:25) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from nltk import pos_tag
>>>
```

So could anyone help me with this? Is there anything wrong with the directory of the file?

Comment: How did you install?

Comment: @flyingmeatball I used sudo pip install -U nltk

Comment: Should I uninstall, and install again?

Comment: In the second case, what does `nltk.__version__` report? Is it the same version of NLTK?

Comment: @DYZ The output is 3.2.2. Does this have anything to do with the version?

Comment: How about the same variable in the first case? If the values are different, you are using two different NLTKs.

Comment: @DYZ Since I only get error from this first case, I don't know the output of 
print(nltk.__version__) in  the first case

Comment: But can you import nltk itself? (Not pos_tag.)

Comment: @DYZ nltk cannot be imported either. Actually I find that I can import nltk from almost all other directories except the folder containing this python script

Comment: Do you incidentally have a file called nltk.py or pos_tag.py in this folder? Or some other file with a name already used by NLTK?

Comment: @DYZ I have checked that, but there is no nltk.py or pos_tag.py in the folder.  But there is a __pycache__ folder inside this folder, and there are 3 .pyc documents in __pycache__ folder. Is this a problem?

Comment: In general, that shouldn't be a problem, but you may want to remove the cache folder and give the script another try. (It is safe.)

Comment: @DYZ It still doesn't work. I am giving up; i'll just move the file to a different folder. Thanks for help!